# How to find a target URI obscured by this dropdown

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping

I'm scraping some data with R and I have URL like this:

http://www.aiuniv.edu/degrees/business/bachelors-business-administration-management-bba

The URLs that I want to get to, which is this one for the example above:

http://www.aiuniv.edu/gedisclosure/gedt-021136-52.0201_aiu_aiu-online_3_bachelorofbusinessadministration.htm

are on the same page from an end user perspective, however before it appears I have to make a selection from this dropdown menu:

```
     <div id="content_6_row_0_locationSelectContainer" class="location-select small-12 medium-6 large-5"> 
        <label for="content_6_row_0_LocationSelect" id="content_6_row_0_CalloutOverviewLabel" class="callout-overview-label"></label>  <!--used to be LocationSelectLabel-->
        <span class="label-title"><label for="content_6_row_0_LocationSelect" id="content_6_row_0_CalloutLocationSelectLabel" class="callout-location-select-label"><span class="labelTitle">To see Gainful Employment and other disclosures, start by selecting a location or Online from the dropdown below:</span><br />
</label></span>           
        <label class="lblSelect"><select name="content_6$row_0$LocationSelect" onchange="if (!ProgramDisclosures.isValidLocation(this)) return false;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'content_6$row_0$LocationSelect\',\'\')', 0)" id="content_6_row_0_LocationSelect">
        <option value="">Select a location</option>
        <option value="">- - - - - - -</option>
        <option value="{9F383A6F-740A-4B0D-BF2E-5F81AAB4CF88}">AIU Atlanta </option>
        <option value="{62FAC854-C48C-42EC-BDD4-F682B2A005D9}">AIU Houston </option>
        <option value="{F9D1E0DD-5B5D-44DB-AC4C-A09BA97A9AE9}">AIU Online </option>

    </select></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The target URL's do not appear in the source code of the original URL, which I've scraped with `read_html` and `htmlParse` in R's `xml2` library.

So how can I use the data from the dropdown to reveal the target URL? For instance, if I want to use the "AIU Online" dropdown option which has a value of `{F9D1E0DD-5B5D-44DB-AC4C-A09BA97A9AE9}` how could I use this to get the part of the page that's currently not showing in the source code?

I would be fine with an answer using R or any "command line" type of solution so that I can integrate it into my R code (just no browser macros or anything GUI like that).

Comment: Ugh. It's a SharePoint-backed site (https://www.evernote.com/l/AAFa6z3LuK9LL4V-6cjgZEjFx5HzxwJ3MZ4). You'll be better off using selenium

Comment: @hrbrmstr I didn't realize that it was SharePoint based, thanks for that.

Comment: Aye. I feel for ya. SP sites are horrible to work with scraping-wise esp if they rely heavily on view state objects (which this one seems to)